# How to fix exe generated from a tkinter example code?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, exe, pyinstaller

I have used pyinstaller to generate exe from this tkinter gui example. But the generated exe in the dist folder does not show any gui. Is it because of the file reading operation? I have followed some examples. But the problem is still there.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

class Checkbar(Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.vars = []
      for pick in picks:
         var = IntVar()
         chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var)
         chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
         self.vars.append(var)
   def state(self):
      return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   dfs = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

   root = Tk()
   root.title("Ship Repairing Time")
   root.geometry("800x600+0+0")
   heading = Label(root, text="Choose the variables you want", font=("arial", 25, "bold"), fg="blue").pack()
   lng = Checkbar(root, ['PLATE', 'SB', 'HC', 'GRT', 'D', 'TC', 'V', 'PA'])
   include = Checkbutton(root, )
   lng.pack(side=TOP,  fill=X)
   T = Text(root, height=25, width=90)
   T.pack()
   selected_columns = []
   x = dfs.iloc[:, 1:]
   print(list(x))
   y = dfs["T"]
   #tgl.pack(side=LEFT)
   lng.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=2)

   def allstates():
      T.delete(1.0,END)
      print(list(lng.state()))
      for i in range(len(list(lng.state()))):
          if list(lng.state())[i] == 1:
              selected_columns.append(list(x)[i])
      print(selected_columns)
      selected_frame = x[selected_columns]
      selected_frame = sm.add_constant(selected_frame)
      model = sm.OLS(y, selected_frame).fit()
      predictions = model.predict(selected_frame)
      T.insert(END, model.summary())

      selected_columns.clear()


   Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=BOTTOM)
   Button(root, text='Calculate', command=allstates).pack(side=TOP)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: add more context to the question. it's hard to understand.

Comment: It is a simple linear regression model. I am just showing it in a GUI. The results are shown in text widget. I ran it in PyCharm. It was ok. But I want it as a exe file.

Comment: Did you include the xlsx file in the exe file? If not, then the program may be terminated due to file not found exception.

Comment: run exe in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error messages.

Comment: the problem is solved now. Thank you, @furas, you helped me to solve this. There were some package problem. statsmodel.tsa was facing some problem.